# Sobre la clase Console en Eclipse. ¿Cómo instanciar? ¿Por qué me da NullPointerException?

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo este sencillo código que por alguna razón no me ejecuta en Eclipse. Me emite el siguiente error `NullPointerException`.

```
Console consol=System.console();
String numero;
System.out.println("numero?");          
numero=consol.readLine();
```

¿Por qué?

Answer (score 2):

Para usar la clase `Console` deberás ejecutarlo desde la consola de comandos para ver los resultados.

En la consola de comandos te ubicas hasta donde esta ubicada la clase que estas usando.

1. Compilas

   `C:\Users\Osorio\ejercicio> javac Ejemplo.java`
2. Ejecutas tu clase

   `C:\Users\Osorio\ejercicio> java Ejemplo`

Answer (score 0):

Es un bug de Eclipse.

System.console() te retorna null. Como consecuencia consol es null y al usarlo te lanza la excepción.
[Este enlace](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429) habla de este caso.

Te recomiendo que para leer datos por teclado uses, por ejemplo, la clase Scanner

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
String cadena = teclado.nextLine();
int entero = teclado.nextInt();
```

Saludos!